# Best way to return SQLite values

Tags: c#, sqlite, return-value

I have a SQLite DB in an Universal Windows APP, and have multi-types (bool, int and Uint64). I need to return all values from my table by ID.

```
    // Id Module
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int id { set; get; }
    // Fix comm state
    public bool commState { set; get; }
    // Fix home sensor state
    public bool homeSensor { set; get; }
    // Fix up sensor state
    public bool upSensor { set; get; }
    // Fix down sensor state
    public bool downSensor { set; get; }
    // Fix actual tier position
    public int actualTier { set; get; }
    // Fix actual step of encoder
    public UInt64 encodPosition { set; get; }
```

I try to return it by a List, but I think I can't return with diferent types.

What is the best approach to return this values together from a SQLite DB?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: yes you can if you create the List<T> as a `var obj = new List<object> ( ) { }` then define your data types within the code

Comment: That's work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MethodMan helps solving the problem.

I have created an object:

```
class objModel
{
    // Id Module   
    public int id { set; get; }
    // Fix comm state
    public bool commState { set; get; }
    // Fix home sensor state
    public bool homeSensor { set; get; }
    // Fix up sensor state
    public bool upSensor { set; get; }
    // Fix down sensor state
    public bool downSensor { set; get; }
    // Fix actual tier position
    public int actualTier { set; get; }
    // Fix actual step of encoder
    public UInt64 encodPosition { set; get; }
}
```

Then use a list of objects:

```
public List<objModel> getParameters()
    {
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), pathDBLocal);

        var sList = db.Table<ModuleDB>();

        List<objModel> mList = new List<objModel>();

        foreach (var item in sList)
        {
            mList.Add(item.objM);                   
        }
        return mList;
    }
```

Thanks Guys... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Entity Framework for returning the object you need. This is a tutorial that will lead you through all the way:

https://erazerbrecht.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/sqlite-entityframework-6-tutorial/

If you want to use ADO.NET, here you have a method that will return a DataSet (using Sqlite.Net):

```
    private static DataSet ExecuteDataset(string DBLocation, string query)
    {
        var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + DBLocation + ";Version=3;");
        DataSet ds;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            ds = new DataSet();
            var da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, conn);
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

Comment: I forget to tell that this is for a Universal Windows APP.
I guess I can't use a dataset. Sorry if I'm wrong...